# ACF / Using external resources to display images

Tags: plugins

Using acf pro, and using image field and gallery fields on my posts form in wp-admin.

I store assets on s3, I'd like those acf fields to display images from cloudfront. Practically speaking, I'd like to rewrite how acf returns images url before displaying it in the wp-admin forms

I don't have much experience yet in wordpress at large, I just don't know where to begin; Is that even cleanly feasible ?

Thx a lot for any experienced insights

Comment: I think ACF doesn’t have anything to do with image uploads. Try using any of plugins that store media to S3, e,g. https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/. ACF just takes link as it is provided by WordPress so you even might not need any additional functionality.

Comment: Did I mention uploads ? As they are, urls  in the database should remain the same. I just need to rewrite URLs that are returned from acf

Comment: Simply do not use an image field, but a text field instead (if it's a gallery, use a repeater field with text fields), and put those s3 urls in said text fields. In your template file or content, you can do something like this:

<img src="<?php the_field('field_name_that_contains_s3_url');?>" />

Comment: @galingong humm nope downgrading the ux is not a solution. only looking for rewriting those url when they're returned